# Convert SimpleXmlElement with one attribute to string

Tags: php, xml

I have some `XML` to be parsed using `SimpleXmlElement` . Since now everything works as it should. I get `XML` and all fields.

Now I need to load values I have parsed into `database`, I am using `PDO` and this is causing some problems because I am trying to save object of `SimpleXmlElement` into field which should be `text`.

Here is my code sample:

```
$score = $cvss->base_metrics->score;
```

`echo $score` result in:

```
9.3
```

although `var_dump($score)` gives

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#9(1) {[0]=> string(3) "9.3"}
```

using `serialize()` on this function result in :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed
```

each try of accesing `[0]` field directly fails... I need `9.3` to be string in order to be able to create `PDO` object. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: cast result to string: `$score = (string)$cvss->base_metrics->score;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php)

```
public string SimpleXMLElement::__toString ( void )
```

*Returns text content that is directly in this element. Does not return text content that is inside this element's children.*

Comment: __toString() is a magic method that defines the behaviour of an object if it is cast to a string. Like `$string = (string)$simpleXmlElement;`.